# How to write an alias in csh/tcsh that can write one file with shebang?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, csh, tcsh

I want to write one script with my alias but not able to add bang line in my script with echo command.
I tried these ways:

```
alias wnc 'echo "#\!/bin/csh " > cshCMD.csh; echo "ncl" >> cshCMD.csh; chmod +x cshCMD.csh; '

alias wnc "echo '#\!/bin/csh ' > cshCMD.csh; echo 'ncl' >> cshCMD.csh; chmod +x cshCMD.csh;"
```

If I run these lines without alias then they work for me.

```
echo "#\!/bin/csh " > cshCMD.csh; echo "ncl" >> cshCMD.csh; chmod +x cshCMD.csh;
```

With direct typing and using command I'll get data in file 
cshCMD.csh as:

- `#!/bin/csh`
- `ncl`

while when I use alias on command line as

```
wnc
```

I got this message :

```
/bin/csh: Event not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `\!` in the expansion of your alias, so you must use `\\!` when defining it. The first backslash disappears during processing of the alias-defining command and the second one protects the `!` when the alias runs.